# Locale Norway/Sweden chcp 65001" and "chcp 1252 CSV File not Formatted correctly

Tags: python, command-line, beautifulsoup, locale, spyder

Hi I was trying to do a tutroial on webscraping and producing a CSV file. using beautiful soup with python and I was getting an error.

one of the suggestions was to go to a command line and enter chcp 65001.

I did this with my anaconda prompt command line (Virtual environment) but it did not fix the fault!

I then fixed the initial fault which involved included writing "encode UTF-8"

The code works but I get some strange characters on the CSV File which is created

For example the date released columns i get something like "2019â€‘02â€‘08" when i should get 2019‑02‑08.

my code is

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# i did this in my anaconda prompt "chcp 65001" and "chcp 1252"
# 

html = urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors')
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
table = bsObj.findAll('table', {'class':'wikitable'})[0]
rows = table.findAll('tr')
csvFile = open('editors.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
try:
    for row in rows:    
        csvRow = []
        for cell in row.findAll(['td', 'th']):
            csvRow.append(cell.get_text())
        writer.writerow(csvRow)
finally:
    csvFile.close()
```

to try and fix it i went back to the Anaconda prompt and typed "chcp 1252" but it did not fix it.

I am using spyder in an anaconda environment.
I hope I have not messed things with these chcp commands :(

Cheers

Comment: How exactly are you viewing the resulting CSV file?

Comment: _and I was getting an error._ What error? It's probably best to start there, rather than to try to fix the attempt at a solution. As an aside, you should use a context manager to handle file objects, and variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel Iam using open "office xcalc" it is office libre's version of excel

Comment: @Karl Knechtel Interesting when I open in notepad I don't get these strange characters. I think you are on to something :)